# How to get texdoc to return a particular document?

Tags: layout, texdoc

I was interested in the `layout` package but when I did

```
texdoc layout
```

it returned the manual for `pst-layout`.

I have the `layout` package on my computer in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/layout.sty
```

I am waiting for the DVD before updating to the 2022 texlive.

Comment: `texdoc texdoc` (I'm not joking) gave me some info. I think you can try the `--list` and `--mixed` flags.

Comment: `texdoc -s layout `

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I typed

```
texdoc -h
```

it responded with a list of options for the command, one of which was `-l` to give a list of all the results for name.

```
Usage: texdoc [OPTION]... NAME...
   or: texdoc [OPTION]... ACTION

Try to find appropriate TeX documentation for the specified NAME(s).
Alternatively, perform the given ACTION and exit.

Options:
  -w, --view        Use view mode: start a viewer. (default)
  -m, --mixed       Use mixed mode (view or list).
  -l, --list        Use list mode: show a list of results.
  -s, --showall     Use showall mode: show also "bad" results.

  -i, --interact    Use interactive menus. (default)
  -I, --nointeract  Use plain lists, no interaction required.
  -M, --machine     Machine-readable output for lists (implies -I).

  -q, --quiet       Suppress warnings and most error messages.
  -v, --verbose     Print additional information (e.g., viewer command).
  -D, --debug       Activate all debug output (equal to "--debug=all").
  -d LIST, --debug=LIST
                    Activate debug output restricted to LIST.
  -c NAME=VALUE     Set configuration item NAME to VALUE.

Actions:
  -h, --help        Print this help message.
  -V, --version     Print the version number.
  -f, --files       Print the list of configuration files used.
  --just-view FILE  Display FILE, given with full path (no searching).

Full manual available via `texdoc texdoc'.

Website: <https://tug.org/texdoc/>
Repository: <https://github.com/TeX-Live/texdoc>
Please email bugs to <texdoc@tug.org>.
```

I tried

```
texdoc -l layout
```

and got

```
1 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pst-layout/pst-layout-doc.pdf
   = Package documentation
 2 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/layout.pdf
 3 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/context/third/layout/t-layout.pdf
   = Package documentation
 4 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/handin/layout.pdf
 5 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex-refsheet/layout.pdf
 6 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/tools/layout.pdf
 7 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/context/third/layout/VERSION
 8 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/refman/layout_d.pdf
   = [de] Layout-Anderungen mit LaTeX
 9 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/refman/layout_e.pdf
   = [en] Changing the layout with LaTeX
10 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pst-layout/README
   = Readme
Enter number of file to view, RET to view 1, anything else to skip:
```

whereupon I entered `2` for the layout package which was the one I was interested in, not `pst-layout`.